# Iterate thru json and get every xth object value

Tags: javascript, json, html, google-sheets-api

How can I iterate thru a JSON object and take every nth value and generate a css grid #id element for.

direct example: I want every value of the third element in the array and populate them below each other in divs.

```
valueRanges: Array(1)
0:
majorDimension: "ROWS"
range: "'ma1'!A1:J38"
values: Array(38)
0: (10) ["maandag 1 april 2019", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "week IV"]
1: Array(10)
0: "kafee"
1: "naam"
2: "functie"
3: "van"
4: "tot"
5: "van"
6: "tot"
7: "Subtotaal"
8: "totaal"
9: "Info"
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
2: Array(10)
0: ""
1: "Ine"
2: ""
3: "9:30"
4: ""
5: ""
6: "18:00"
7: "8,5"
8: "8"
9: "Reservaties/opmerkingen"
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
3: (9) ["", "Michiel", "", "9:30", "", "", "17:30", "8", "7,5"]
```

I get the data with

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = response.result.valueRanges[0].values[0][0];
```

```
var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet(params);
      request.then(function(response) {
        // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
        console.log(response.result);
        document.getElementById("currentday").innerHTML = response.result.valueRanges[0].values[0][0];
        document.getElementById("StartHourOne").innerHTML = response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][3];
        document.getElementById("EndHourOne").innerHTML = response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][6];

        document.getElementById("BarTeamNightNameOne").innerHTML = response.result.valueRanges[0].values[11][1];
```

I could do this for every cell in the sheet, but I have a lot of cells in that sheet.

I’m hoping I can make use of the returning structure in the JSON.

I've been able to manually add the cells. for every object but I think I need a for loop for this.

So tried a for loop for this but this didn't work.

```
valueRanges: Array(1)
0:
majorDimension: "ROWS"
range: "'ma1'!A1:J38"
values: Array(38)
0: (10) ["maandag 1 april 2019", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "week IV"]
1: Array(10)
0: "kafee"
1: "naam"
2: "functie"
3: "van"
4: "tot"
5: "van"
6: "tot"
7: "Subtotaal"
8: "totaal"
9: "Info"
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
2: (10) ["", "Ine", "", "9:30", "", "", "18:00", "8,5", "8", "Reservaties/opmerkingen"]
```

The values array shows 0 - 38 other arrays that are going from 0 - 10. Now for example every 0 - 10 array has the same data on its parent array (0 - 38). How could I iterate that I populate new div elements with every 1st value of for example 0 - 14 parent arrays.

I've tried following based upon @Kiryhas eaction.

But that gives me the following.

Following code :

```
const object1 = { response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][1] , 1: response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][3], 2: response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][6], 3: response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][7]};
        console.log(Object.entries(object1));
```

Gives me this result:

```
(4) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
0: "0"
1: "Ine"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
1: (2) ["1", "9:30"]
2: Array(2)
0: "2"
1: "18:00"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
3: (2) ["3", "8,5"]
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

As I just want the array elements 1, 3, 6, 7  of the following array per array

```
2: Array(10) (or any other array)
0: ""
1: "Ine"
2: ""
3: "9:30"
4: ""
5: ""
6: "18:00"
7: "8,5"
8: "8"
9: "Reservaties/opmerkingen"
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much you care about the keys in that object you can iterate over the values or key-value pairs using `Object.keys(yourObject)` or `Object.entries(yourObject):`

```
const object1 = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
console.log(Object.entries(object1)[1]);
// expected output: Array ["baz", 42]

const object2 = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(object2)[2]);
// expected output: Array ["2", "c"]

const result = Object.entries(object2).sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(Object.entries(result)[1]);
```

> expected output: Array ["1", Array ["1", "b"]]

For reference try below links

[Global_Objects/Object/values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

[Global_Objects/Object/entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

This will allow you to go through them with a loop that targets each Nth value.

Comment: I've done this         
```const object1 = { 0: response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][1] , 1: response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][3], 2: response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][6], 3: response.result.valueRanges[0].values[2][7]};
        console.log(Object.entries(object1));
```
Which works but I would need to do this 38 times, and what happens when added a new value array then I would need to add it to the code. It works but is there a "better" way? Thanks anyways!!